# Stop a Windows 7 PC from going to sleep while a Ruby program executes

Tags: ruby, windows-7, sleep

I need to run a Ruby app on a customer computer. It will usually take a couple of days to finish (copies big backup files). The problem is if sleep is enabled, it will interrupt the app. If not the computer will stay on for weeks untill my next visit. Is there some way to prevent sleep during execution and let Windows sleep after?

Any crazy ideas are welcome ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't do much on the Windows platform, but the following approach seems logical:

1. In your program, use whatever ruby libs are available for the windows platform to check whether auto suspend/sleep is enabled.
2. If enabled, disable it.
3. Run your long tasks.
4. Once done, re-enable auto suspend/sleep

You are probably going to need to add some additional logic to re-enable auto suspend if your program errors out.

Also, the application may need to be run under an account that has access to enable/disable auto suspend.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 6):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/585982/how-do-i-stop-my-computer-from-going-into-sleep-or-hibernate-mode) is upvoted advice to use [SetThreadExecutionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373208%28VS.85%29.aspx) WinAPI function, which *enables an application to inform the system that it is in use, thereby preventing the system from entering sleep or turning off the display while the application is running.*
Something like:

```
require 'Win32API'
ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040
ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000
ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002
ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
func = Win32API.new 'kernel32','SetThreadExecutionState','L'

func.call(ES_CONTINUOUS|ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)
# doing your stuff...
func.call(ES_CONTINUOUS)
```

---

Or just put something on keyboard (you said *crazy ideas are welcome*)

Comment: In addition it might be really user-friendly to check and see if you're running on battery or the charger. If it's a long-running process and you're on battery and you're not letting the machine sleep you could drain the battery and cause everything to fail. That would make me say bad words.

Comment: To go with your crazy idea of putting something on the keyboard, you could set an optical mouse with the laser on top of an analog watch :) That way you don't have to worry about random input from the keyboard

Answer (score 2):

If this is a command-line program, then you can send commands from Ruby to the command line using backticks like this

```
puts `command here`
```

so then you can set the computer to not sleep by sending this command

`c:\windows\system32\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0`

like this

```
puts `c:\\windows\\system32\\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 0`
```

You have to escape the `\` with the double. Tested and works for me, although on a laptop. I assume it would function the same on a desktop.

The number at the very end is the time in minutes before putting the computer to sleep. I don't know if you can retrieve the original value, but you can set it to any number.  Thus, to put the computer to sleep after 10 minutes, you would send

```
puts `c:\\windows\\system32\\powercfg.exe -change -standby-timeout-ac 10`
```

So you can turn off sleep at the beginning of the script and turn the sleep back on afterwards.

Hope this is suitable for you!

Comment: You also must know current sleep timeout to recover it properly after program executed.

Comment: @Nakilon, that is why I mentioned that I do not know if it is possible to retrieve the current setting. The OP did not specify a requirement on that front. This would work for the simple premise of preventing sleep, and then allowing sleep afterwards so the machine is not left on for multiple weeks.

Comment: Also, since the OP mentioned `weeks until my next visit`, he could possibly check the current sleep setting manually, and then adjust the time for the 2nd command prior to running his app (assuming it is not compiled some way).